# Multilingual AJAX application

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, multilingual, template-engine

I'm building a web application using a lot of javascript and AJAX. This app has to be multilingual.

On the server side, I have a little template-engine coded in PHP which handles translation files. But on the client side, I sometimes display text and I need to translate it following the same rules. I do not want to make an http request every time I need to display a message, so what is the best way to do it?

In other words, how to build an unified translation system working both server and client side?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a server side script which will serve dynamic javascript containing the translated variables according to the user preferences. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/translations.php?language=fr"></script>
```

This script could contain a global variable with the translations:

```
var values = { hello: 'Bonjour', goodbye: 'Au revoir' };
...
```

The script will be cached by client browsers and used in your scripts:

```
alert(values.hello);
```

Just make sure you setup proper HTTP response cache headers so that the clients need to fetch those values only once, probably when choosing a language. Obviously the server side script could also use the `Accept-Language` HTTP request header to determine the client preferences instead of a query string parameter.